# time stamp when posting questions/answers

Tags: feature-request

When people post/answer questions here, time stamp doesn't show the year. I think the year in time stamp is very important. Technology and solution change fast . It will be helpful to add the year in time stamp. It will help people to filter information that are outdated.. 
Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on meta.stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

The year will appear if you hover your mouse over the date.

Answer (score 4):

The timestamp "ages" gracefully so that as a post gets older, the timestamp shows more information about when it was asked/answered.  If a timestamp is missing information, you can assume that it is the most recent "whatever" corresponding to the date fragment -- year, month, day, as appropriate.  As others have noted, you can always hover over the timestamp to get the full date and time.

Comment: This isn't quite right -- the year is shown only if the date is more than a year ago. For example, a SO post appearing on 1 Nov 2008 will only show the timestamp "Nov 28", not "Nov 28 '08".

Comment: I've corrected this.